# In Blazor, https and core hosted option

Tags: .net-core, https, blazor, asp.net-core-hosted-services

1. When I make a project in visual studio 2019, there's a https checkbox option.
   Let's say I didn't checked https option.
   How can I mannually add or remove https option?

Also when I run my https option enabled project and connect through my external ip address,
I see certificate warning page. How to solve that?

2. What is the diffrence between having core hosted option and not?
   How can I enable or disable core hosted mannually?

Answer (score 1):

In Startup on the server

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
   ...
}
else
{
    ...
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

Then it is just a matter of amending the `Properties\launchSettings.json` in both the client and server projects.

```
"sslPort": 44346   <-- use a unique port not this one specifically
```

and further down

```
"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second part of your question, when you specify ASP.NET Core Hosting to your Blazor WebAssembly application, Visual Studio creates three projects:  Client, Server, and Shared.

Hence if you want to add core hosting after the fact, you need to add at least a Blazor Server project to your solution (to host the Web Api calls).  Ideally you can also add a Shared project (Class Library) to host models that are shared between Client and Server.

Finally when you scaffold an ASP.NET Core Hosted application, the FetchData.razor page is retrieving WeatherForecast via an API call on the server; in a non-core hosted app, FetchData.razor retrieves WeatherForecast from a locally hosted file.